# make a loop js / remove a possible list of errors that would be already present

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, email

I want to know how to make a loop that would allow me to choose which form I want the action takes place, and as for the chosen form the function that allows me to display an alert appears and not the other form.

My function is intended to display an error if email is incorrect when leaving the fields. I manage to display the error on my first form with id `id_st-courriel` but not the second because I do not know how to choose a loop between the two
My second fields for email id `id_em-courriel`

My problem is that when I leave the fields email and I come back over there raffiche me a second line identical mistakes I would then be able to make disappear this line if this error has already been present. This is my js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#id_st-courriel").focusout(checkEmailField);
    });

    function checkEmailField() {    
        $fieldValue = $("input#id_st-courriel").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/checkEmailField',
            data: ({
                value: $fieldValue
            }),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
                if ($data != '') {
                    $("input#id_st-courriel").parent().prev('errorlist').remove();
                    $("input#id_st-courriel").parent().before($data);
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

> This is my views.py

```
def ajax_check_email_field(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    HTML_to_return = ''
    if 'value' in request.GET:
        field = forms.EmailField()
        try:
            field.clean(request.GET['value'])
        except exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
            HTML_to_return = '<ul class="errorList">'
            for message in ve.messages:
                HTML_to_return += '<li>' + message + '</li>'
            HTML_to_return += '</ul>'
    return HttpResponse(HTML_to_return)
```

My last two lines probably will not work. This is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: I think you're assuming that should $data hold an errorlist tag, but I would double check.  However there is no smoking gun.  It should work if all assumptions are correct.  So double-check your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below JS code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $("input#id_st-courriel").focusout(checkEmailField('id_st-courriel'));
    $("input#id_em-courriel").focusout(checkEmailField('id_em-courriel'));
     });

function checkEmailField(id) {
    $fieldValue = $("input#" + id).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/checkEmailField',
        data: ({
            value: $fieldValue
        }),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function ($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
            if ($data != '') {
                $("input#" + id).parent().prev('errorlist').remove();
                $("input#" + id).parent().before($data);
            }
          }
      })
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: i have try and it appears This field is required all the time on the 2 forms

Comment: I could not get it what you are trying to say.You mean to say the focusout event is not firing.Then you can use On ,                                  on.( "focusout", handler )